# Can't load JSTL in multi module maven project with embedded jetty

Tags: jetty, jstl, tld

I have created a test framework for testing .jsp files and .tag files using embedded jetty. I'm starting Jetty server programmatically using Java API, adding servlet holder and wrapper test JSP and initializing the server passing the project's web root.
There were some issues with Jasper discovering TLD locations during runtime when run from maven surefire plugin. I fixed it by providing

```
<useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar>
```

plugin classpath settings. Everything works good when I run tests using mvn clean install now.
Running tests from eclipse context menu has one issue. If there is any other project in workspace in the multi module maven build, TLD's in that project are not resolved. One workaround I tried was to 'close' the project in eclipse workspace and it worked out.

However I would want it to work with all the projects open in workspace and running from the eclipse JUnit context menu. The problem is in the jasper TldScanner that looks for tld files in jar and WEB-INF of current project only.

```
TldScanner.scanTlds()
        processWebDotXml();
        scanJars();
        processTldsInFileSystem("/WEB-INF/");
```

I'm using org.glassfish.web.jsp-impl 2.2.2-b06 version with Jetty-8.1.0-RC5.
Is there a way to specify file based TLD scanning for jasper for extra classpath items?

Comment: I would update to the latest Jetty 8 release, 8.1.14.v20131031 at the time of this comment.  If this remains an issue open a bug at bugs.eclipse.org under RT/Jetty and we will try and take a look.